# global name 'client' no defined, while using foursquare api in django

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-views, foursquare

So I'm using this django  [foursquare api](https://github.com/mLewisLogic/foursquare).
I have installed but when I try to write

```
client = foursquare.Foursquare(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID', client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET', redirect_uri='http://fondu.com/oauth/authorize')
```

I get an error: 'module' object has no attribute 'Foursquare'
also if I remove this and try to use client anywhere in my code I get the error: global name 'client' is not defined.

I am trying to get checkin updates of a venue to my app.

Comment: How are you importing `foursquare`? Are you sure that `foursquare` in your code is the library that you gave link to? How did you install the library?

Comment: Lib: pip install foursquare ; as instructed.
IMPORT: import foursquare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've called your own script foursquare.py, so Python is importing that instead of the library. Rename your script to something else.